# Debugging Cordova application in the browser

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to find a good way to develop an Cordova application in the browser without the need to build and run the Cordova applocation any change I made to the HTML, CSS or Javascript.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to do so. I tried to open the relevant folder in the browser but of course I have the cordova.js missing.

Any way I can test and debug simple HTML/CSS/Javascript changes on the browser?

I don't care about cordova plugins at this point - I just want to be able to change color or jQuery without building cordova to my device again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with chrome in Android:

You just have to compile in a emulator or device, plug in in the computer, enter chrome and type:

```
chrome://inspect
```

If your device is correctly configured, you can see it in the screen, just click in "inspect" under your application, et voila!

more info: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

In IOS, is easier, but with less options. Just compile the project to your device from XCode, enter safari, and select "development" in the top tabs. You can see there your device with the aplication. You can change css and launch some jQuery, but you can't change javascript "on the fly"

Comment: I can debug that way but I wanted to debug like it was just a website

Comment: Then just remove all your references to cordova plugins, and open your index.html in a navigator

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which plugins you're using and how critical they are to your application, you can [install Cordova's browser](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/09/24/Browser-as-a-platform-for-your-PhoneGapCordova-apps) platform and work with that like you would a normal website.

Comment: I'll give it a try, Thanks!